How to get the Apple Pay Pane in Objective-C on MacOS
I’m a bit stumped, because we rarely use objective-c in our project  (QT crossplatform,no X-Code at all, signing, entitlements, etc all done with commandline tools) and, up to now, no window stuff at all. (Except what gets triggered automatically, like Permission panes for Photokit, folders, etc.)
I built the PaymentRequest and according to NSLog it works.
      if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments]) {
          NSLog(@"Can Make Payments");
      }
      else {
          NSLog(@"Cannot Make Payments");
      }
   

Removing or adding the supported card from the request also works.
      if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController
      canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:paymentNetworks
              capabilities:(PKMerchantCapabilityDebit | PKMerchantCapabilityCredit)
       ])
     {
        NSLog(@"Card Supported");
     } else {
        NSLog(@"Card Not Supported");
        }

So I do get Can Make Payments and   Card Supported
This also works in compile and execution,
    PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *paymentPane = [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];

But I don’t manage to raise the request
NSWindow *mainWindow = [NSApplication sharedApplication].windows[0];
[mainWindow.contentViewController presentViewControllerAsModalWindow:paymentPane];

My code is in
    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 

I do get a window, as expected, but that’s all.
The payment request is basically just the “supported cards” and the total, i.e. all we need is the authorisation token we would then send to the backend.  The mobile team up has this up and running, but of course, they are all Swift these days and couldn’t help more than they already did.

Is mainWindow.contentViewController nil?

Nope.      NSLog(@"%@",mainWindow); says
<NSWindow: 0x12c606490>
or, next run,
<NSWindow: 0x135f07dd0>
Which I interpret as “This is an NSWindow object starting at address 0x135f07dd0.”

Try NSLog(@"%@", mainWindow.contentViewController);.

Huh. That's actually NULL. So progress, of sorts.

The  problem was that the code was in  applicationDidFinishLaunching.
Once we set up a probleme UI with a button linked to calling Apple Pay, the Pane appeared.
